# how to access an element of arraylist in jsp when index is a variable?

Tags: jsp, arraylist, springsource

i m accessing an element in an arraylist. the problem arises as the index of the required element is a variable. can anyone plz help me?

eg `<td><c:out value="${PARENT_MODULE[module.moduleId]}"> </c:out></td>`

here module.moduleId is a variable.

i have already tried

```
<c:out value="${PARENT_MODULE[${module.moduleId}]}">
```

however this gives an error.

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/showModules.jsp(40,20) "${PARENT_MODULE[${module.moduleId}]}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: ${PARENT_MODULE[${module.moduleId}]}

thanks

Comment: You don't need to use ${} around `module.moduleId`, `<c:out value="${PARENT_MODULE[module.moduleId]}">` should work.

Comment: thank you so much! 
i never tried that.. as i thought that was highly unlikely..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `PARENT_MODULE` is the alias you gave the array of `modules`
Assuming `module` is the object and `moduleId` is an attribute in the module object

try this:

```
< c:out value="${PARENT_MODULE[num].moduleId}"/>
```

where `num` is a number. `PARENT_MODULE[num]` would return the object `module` at the "**num**" position in the array. and after that all you have to do is access the `moduleId` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

As `module.moduleId` is inside an EL expression, it will be evaluated. So you don't need to enclose it in an additional ${}.

`<c:out value="${PARENT_MODULE[module.moduleId]}">` will work.